# sqlbulkcopy The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type bigint of the specified target column

Tags: vb.net

im trying to do a blukcopy into the TLC_PRODUCTS_LOAD page and im getting an an error which is

> The given value of type String from the data source cannot be
> converted to type bigint of the specified target column.

i tried to change the datatype for the table

Comment: You need to provide much more information than that. The error message sends pretty clear: you're trying to insert text into a numeric column. If you expect specific help then you have to provide specific information about what you're doing. Database table schema, DataTable schema, code, etc.

Comment: It sounds like there is a rogue value (or more than one) in one (or more than one) of the columns of the data source. You will need to check that all the strings can be parsed into the type(s) you need. For example, an empty string could be a problem. (N.B.: telephone "numbers" cannot be stored in a numeric type.)